# I need C++ API similar to fn_get_audit_file procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, smo, audit, ssms, audit-trail

I want to programmatically read audit trail files(.sqlaudit) logged in SQL Server 2008 R2.
I wish they are be able to be viewed without using queries of SQL Server but with functions such as C++ API.
I want to implement an application program reading audit trail files without helps of SQL Server database functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any off-the-shelf component, but you could roll your own wrapper using C#, C++ or VB.Net, providing you have the coding skills to do so.

This Microsoft article might help with some of the detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015.aspx

Also this utility might assist with your endeavours too http://www.logbinder.com/products/LOGbinderSQL/default.aspx

Cheers,
Mark